# SpringIDE 2.6.0 failing to initialize with error under Helios

Tags: eclipse-3.6, spring-ide

I'm running into an issue with the Spring IDE release 2.6.0 under Eclipse 3.6 SR 1

```
Error occured processing XML 'Could not instantiate bean class 
[org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 
'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.'. 
See Error Log for more details
```

I dumped my entire eclipse environment and re-installed to see if it would fix it and it didn't.  Not sure if this is a classpath problem or something specifically related to the SpringIDE configuration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're hitting a bug in Spring IDE. See the following JIRA for more details:

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1691

We are going to publish a patch for this issue soon. Check the JIRA for when it is available. Alternatively install an upcoming nightly build.

Regards, Christian

Comment: Christian, sorry for the delay on the bounty ... didn't realize I had to act on it.